# Azure Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a blob using Jupyter Notebook to Azure Storage. I have a sample code as below:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

accountName = "< account name>"
ContainerSAS = "<SAS key>"
containerName = "< container name>"

try:
    sas_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, sas_token=ContainerSAS)
except Exception as e:
    print("There was an error during SAS service creation. Details: {0}".format(e))

from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings

blobName = "< blob name >"
try:
    sas_service.create_blob_from_path(
       'accountName',
       'blobName',
       'Chicago_Crime_Data-v2.csv',
       content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='Chicago_Crime_Data-v2/csv')
    )
except Exception as e:
    print("There was an error during blob uploading. Details: {0}".format(e))
```

But I am getting an error which says: Details: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

I am not able to understand what is wrong here. I am a newbie. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Should I provide the account name, container name and key?

Comment: can you solve the issue by my post? if you still have issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you generate the sas token as per this screenshot:

[image]

There is also an error in the `sas_service.create_blob_from_path` method, the first parameter should be `container_name`, not `account_name`

The following code works well at my side:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, ContentSettings

accountName = "xxx"
ContainerSAS = "xxx"
containerName = "test4"

sas_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName,sas_token=ContainerSAS)

blobname = "222.PNG"

sas_service.create_blob_from_path(containerName,blobname,"F:\\azure stack overflow\\2019\\09\\30\\disk.PNG")

print("done")
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @ivanyang 

The csv file got uploaded, but the storage explorer is not able to identify the file type. Any idea how that can be corrected?

Comment: Thank you @ivanyang I have figured it out the csv issue

Answer (score 3):

My local file path was "./rootfolder" and then when it found a file to upload, it would be like file="./rootfolder/folder/file.dcm"

so then I tried to upload that file wholesale:

```py
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=file)
```

And then I got the following error:

> Azure Server failed to authenticate the request

and

> AuthenticationErrorDetail:The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT...

I found you had to something like this instead, to remove that `./` from the file path.

```py
file_path_on_azure = file_name.replace("./", "")
 
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=file_path_on_azure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly verify whether your account Key is right and also ensure that your system time is set correctly , If your system time is set incorrect you might get "Failed to Authenticate" error.

Comment: Account key and system time looks fine. Is there anything wrong with the code?