# Azure Blob Storage Python SDK MAC signature

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I generate sas and can access to file but when i pass url to blob client to upload_file_url it trow exception

```
try:
#getting container client
blob_container_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url,account_key).get_container_client(container=container_name)

#generate sas tocket for block container
sas=(BlobSharedAccessSignature(account_name, account_key).\
    generate_container(container_name,permission='r',start='2021-03-01T00:00Z',expiry='2021-04-01T00:00Z'))

#generate final url with sas
final_source_url=(blob_container_client.url+'/'+sourcefile+'?'+sas)
print(final_source_url)

blob_client1=blob_container_client.get_blob_client(sourcefile)
source=blob_client1.download_blob().readall()

#---------ACCOUNT 2---------------------
# getting container client for second account
blob_client2 = BlobServiceClient(account_url2, account_key2).get_blob_client(container=container_name2,blob=destinationfile2)
blob_client2.upload_blob_from_url(final_source_url)
```

except Exception as ex:
print('Exception:')
print(ex)

```
Exception:
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:527a4df5-501e-003e-03d6-0f4d5b000000
Time:2021-03-03T02:41:38.6605824Z
ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
Error:None
AuthenticationErrorDetail:The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT

x-ms-client-request-id:f9918e5a-7bc9-11eb-86ab-803049852acd
x-ms-copy-source:://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-ms-date:Wed, 03 Mar 2021 02:41:37 GMT
x-ms-version:2020-06-12
/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/testt.txt'.
```

SAS is for reading from account1 then account2 upload file using sas.
i want copy file from account1 to account2 .

exception is in this line:
blob_client2.start_copy_from_url('final_source_url')

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164698/azure-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request/67679100#67679100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the permissions in your shared access signature. You're creating a shared access signature with just `read (r)` permission (which is fine for reading the blob) however you're trying to perform a write operation with that shared access signature (copy operation is a write operation).

```
sas=(BlobSharedAccessSignature(account_name, account_key).\
    generate_container(container_name,permission='r',start='2021-03-01T00:00Z',expiry='2021-04-01T00:00Z'))
```

Please change your signature to include `write (w)` permission and you should not get this error. Something like the following:

```
sas=(BlobSharedAccessSignature(account_name, account_key).\
    generate_container(container_name,permission='rw',start='2021-03-01T00:00Z',expiry='2021-04-01T00:00Z'))
```

Comment: SAS is for reading from account1 then account2 upload file using sas. i want copy file from account1 to account2 .

Comment: In which line of your code you're getting the exception?

Comment: Also, can you please share the complete code? You mentioned `upload_file_url` in your question but I could not find it in the code snippet you shared. Only thing I see is `start_copy_from_url`.

Comment: in this line: **blob_client2.start_copy_from_url(final_source_url)**

Comment: I try method : **upload_blob_from_url** and its trow the same exception

Comment: This is quite weird. Let me check.

Comment: Thanks, I search a lot and there no cases like this. I think error is to simpler or to weird because i cant find anything.

Comment: So I tried on my own and I was able to use your code successfully. Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/gmantri/71118989dc6c344701ba160787137bf3. HTH.

Comment: Thanks you for helping me! You use your keys in code or sys variable ?

Comment: I’m using keys.